# Java generics method to filter and find first element in list

Tags: java, generics

```
private Feature findFeature(String name, List<Feature> list) {
    for (Feature item : list) {
        if (item.getName().equals(name)) {
            return  item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have 10 other methods like this. Same signature, same logic. Only different is that List parameter is using different objects, e.g. `List<Data> list`, or `List<Option> list`, etc. All objects has a `getName()` method in it. I want to create a generic method and remove all others.

If I use something like this,

```
private <T> T findInList(String name, List<T> list) {
```

I don't have access the `getName()` method. What is the easiest way to create this method? Is reflection api the only option?

EDIT:

I found the mistake I did. It is working just fine like this:

```
for (FeatureEntity entity : data.getFeatures()) {
    Predicate<Feature> filter = f -> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(entity.getName());
    if (entity.getFeatureId() != null && findInList(featureList, filter) == null) {
        FeatureEntity n = new FeatureEntity();
        n.setId(entity.getId());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a `Named` interface that specifies `getName()` and use `? extends Named`.

Comment: The reason, why all these classes have the same attribute `name` and are looked up in the same pattern shouts out the desired use of inheritance in your case.

Comment: About your edit, the code `Predicate<Feature> filter = f -> f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("name");
        findInList(List.of(new Feature("name")), filter);` just works fine. You need to share the MCVE, maybe as a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create generic method that takes generic list with `Predicate` to get the first matching item after filtering

```
private <T> T findFeature(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return list.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

And then create `Predicate` with required type and call that method

```
Predicate< Feature > filter = f->f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name);
findFeature(list,filter);
```

On another side, you can also return `Optional<T>` instead of `null` when no element is found:

```
private <T> Optional<T> findFeature(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return list.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the method call as well to show how predicate looks like?

Comment: I get error while trying to call this method. It says `required List<T>, provided List<Feature>`

Comment: can you update the code in the post and make sure you are on java 8 or above @Yonetmen

Comment: one would end up creating `Predicate<Feature> filter`, `Predicate<Data> filter` etc using this then..

Comment: @Deadpool Wow! It's my bad, I am sorry! There are two objects types. One is entity (`FeatureEntity`) and the other one is auto generated (xsd) model class (`Feature`). We use model class for `getName()` and then iterate through the entity list inside the method.

Comment: that's good point @Naman, he can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708884/9959152 for another approach

Comment: That was mine first choise but since these classes are xsd generated classes, I really want to avoid to alter xsd schemas to introduce the interface and update all the classes. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Deadpool my mistake again. It is working fine. These two different object types confused me. Thanks again!

Comment: On another note, I would suggest rather return an `Optional<T>` from this method instead of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a common `Named` interface, like

```
public interface Named {
    String getName();
}
```

Then use a wildcard to specify that the method requires that `Named` interface.

```
private <T extends Named> T findInList(String name, List<T> list)
```

Then you can use `getName`. Of course, you need to modify the classes you wish to use to `implements Named` (but you mentioned they all already have `getName()` methods).

Comment: ...and clear to state that the classes such as `Feature`, `Data` etc in the question must implement this `interface` then.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need an Inferface:

```
public interface HasName {
    String getName();
}
```

then, your `Feature` class has to implement it:

```
public class Feature implements HasName {
```

After you add the `implements` to your class name, you need to implement the `getName()` method (let your IDE help you with this)

then go as follows:

```
private <T extends HasName> findFeature(String name, List<T> list) {
    // Do your logic, getName will be availible here.
}
```